# Text cursor for JTextPane with HTML

Tags: java, cursor, jtextpane

I have the following problem: I want to change the cursor of a `JTextPane` with content type `text/html` to `Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR`. However, when setting `setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR))` it is ignored. I also tried to set the cursor in the mouse listener, but it is also directly changes back to the standard cursor. If the content type is `text/plain`, the cursor is by default the text cursor. Does any one has an idea how to reach this goal? I created an SCCEE to show this behavior:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class TextPaneHtmlCursor extends JFrame {
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JTextPane jTextPane1;     

    public TextPaneHtmlCursor() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new JTextPane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");
        jTextPane1.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        pack();
    }                    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextPaneHtmlCursor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a little bit more digging, it would seem the the `EditorKit` (in this case `HTMLEditorKit`) is responsible for making the decisions about what cursor should be used.

You can change the "default" cursor using something like...

```
jTextPane1.setContentType("text/html");
((HTMLEditorKit)tp.getEditorKit()).setDefaultCursor(cursor);
```

The default "default" is defined as `private static final Cursor DefaultCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);` which is very annoying...

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. This solution worked for me!